# android: how can a edit a row in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, row

Greeting everyone.
I've just made a listview and now I want to edit each row to add different pictures. As the images are all form the Internet, I want to add them by myself.Can anyone tell me how to get a row for the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own list adapter. If you're going to be loading images from the web, I suggest you do what's called "lazy loading", which is where you download the images as you need them. They're displayed in the list as soon as they've been downloaded but the user can still scroll up and down the list. Checkout this [example](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/) for more details. It shows you how to put images in your list and how to lazily load them.

Answer (score 0):

Implement listview using adapter and in the getview method of the adpter , you can get each row of the list and edit the content of the row.

Here is a [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) for a tutorial where it is well explained.